# Как определить полноэкранный режим браузера в mac os

Tags: javascript, macos, mac, браузер

В маке есть два полноэкранного режима, первый это через <kbd>F11</kbd>, он идентичен с другими осями. Второй режим, только для маков, он растягивает браузер на весь экран <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Как через js определить, в каком режиме браузер находится? Условно для мака есть 3 состояния браузера, назовем их default, fullscreen, native fullscreen

Comment: А зачем это нужно?

Comment: `первый это через F11, он идентичен с другими осями` – не вижу такого режима. Если нажать на зеленую кнопку в левом верхнем углу окна, эффект тот же, что от Ctrl+Cmd+F.